# problem with lightning:input

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inputfield

i have a problem with the tag `<lightning:input type="number">`. I want to insert max 3 integer and 3 decimal (999,999 or 1,0), i try to use this:

```
<lightning:input type="number" step="any" pattern="[0-9]{3},[0-9]{3}" min="0" aura:id="numberId" required="true" maxlength="6" label="numberLabel" name="numberName" />
```

but when i insert 1234,5678 the field show me 1.234,567 but if i click again on inputField the value is 1234,5678 (the lose onBlur cut the four decimal number, but when i click on field i see this (what value it will save? 1.234,567 or 1.234,5678?)). How i can insert max only 3 integer and 3 decimal without problem when i save?
ps: maxlength doesn't work :/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. With your code, I get "12,345,678" as displayed value. Even without the focus.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this**

```
<lightning:input type="number" step="any" pattern="[0-9]{3},[0-9]{3}" min="0" aura:id="numberId" required="true" maxlength="6" label="numberLabel" name="numberName" step="0.001"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically,
Step attribute in <lightning:input type="number"> tag enable decimal number entry, specify a value for step that represents the number of decimal places accepted and the increment.

For example, specifying step=".01" permits numbers such as 0.99 and 123456.78.
The default stepping value for range inputs is 1,then a step of 1 will allow only values such as 1.5, 2.5, 3.5.

```
<lightning:input type="number" step="0.001" pattern="[0-9]{3},[0-9]{3}" min="0" aura:id="numberId" required="true" maxlength="6" label="numberLabel" name="numberName" />
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. It might just be too early and my brain isn't working yet, but I'm not seeing how this answers the question being asked.